# HTML table border only in middle

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make a table with a line right down the middle with CSS. No other borders aside from the center of the table.
My table is 2x4
I tried to use the attached code but it adds lines on outside left and right

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: none;
}

td {
  border-right: solid 1px #f00;
  border-left: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `td` rule to use the [`first-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child) like:

```
td:first-child {
  border-right: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

Example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: none;
}

td:first-child {
  border-right: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'll have to look into what x-child actually does.